# HTMLAgilityPack repeating output

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using HTMLAgilityPack to parse cells from a table. From my understanding, this code should only output "test" once. But for some reason, it outputs "test" twice, and twice more every 10 seconds.

Image of output: https://i.gyazo.com/714a880a626c262b03df2b49dcb7711a.png

Am I doing something wrong, or is this an issue with HTMLAgilityPack? I've tried multiple solutions to accomplish this on StackOverflow and other tutorial websites, but every solution I tried has done this. I need to be able to read every cell, and this is just me testing out if I could just get one output without a repeat, but I guess I can't.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<tr><td>test</td><td>test 2</td></tr>");

var rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr");

if (rows != null && rows.Count > 0)
{
      foreach (var row in rows)
      {
            var cells = row.SelectNodes(".//td");
            Console.WriteLine(cells[0].InnerText);
            return;
       }
}
```

Comment: You are not showing us the relevant code. What calls this method? Please show us a [mcve]

Comment: You're only accessing the **first** cell after calling `SelectNodes()`. You need to iterate over the **entire** collection: `var cells = row.SelectNodes(".//td"); foreach (var cell in cells) { Console.WriteLine(cell.InnerText); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not getting the error you're describing.  Therefore, there the issue must lie in any code you are using to call what you posted in your question.  I don't know what that calling code is, but below is some code that reads all cells in a table.

First, the table:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(@"
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test 3</td>
            <td>test 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
");
```

I added a row to your example.

Now, I assume you want to put the values into a strongly typed IEnumerable of some sort.  So here's the class upon which the IEnumerable will be based:

```
public class StronglyTypedRow {
    public string columnOne {get;set;}
    public string columnTwo {get;set;}
}
```

And now the code that reads the Html data into a strongly typed object:

```
var importedTable = new List<StronglyTypedRow>();

var rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr");

if (rows != null && rows.Count > 0) {

    foreach (var row in rows) {

        var cells = row.SelectNodes(".//td");

        var importedRow = 
            new StronglyTypedRow {
                columnOne = cells[0].InnerText,
                columnTwo = cells[1].InnerText
            };

        importedTable.Add(importedRow);

    }
}
```

If you desire to read it in the console:

```
for(var r = 0; r < importedTable.Count(); r++) {
    var ir = importedTable[r];
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Row " + r + 
        " | Column 1 = " + ir.columnOne + 
        ", Column 2 = " + ir.columnTwo 
    );
}
```

Hope it helps.